# Linking c++-class for boost_python in cygwin

Tags: python, c++, boost, g++, cygwin

I have been using a wrapper for a c++-class for exporting functions to python for a while on linux. Now I wanted to make this available to my coworkers using windows. However, I fail to create a usable boost_python dll for this in cygwin. The problem arises when trying to link a dependent module in another dll, if I instead compile the dependent source into the same dll it works as expected.

I have a created a minimal example displaying the problem:

The setup:

> moduleB/moduleB.cpp # The boost wrapper code

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>

#include "submodule.hpp"

using namespace boost::python;
using namespace testspace;
using namespace std;

struct cModuleB : public SubModuleClass {
    cModuleB(string name, bool boolVar) : SubModuleClass(name,     boolVar) {
    }

    void printFunc(string strVar, list listVar, int nIntVar=-1) {
        vector<int> vecList;
        for (int l=0; l < len(listVar); l++) {
            vecList.push_back(extract<int>(listVar[l]));
        }
        bool bMoreThanHalf = subModuleFunction(vecList);
        if (bMoreThanHalf) {
            cout << "More than half elements are more than 1";
        }
        return;
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(moduleB)
{
    class_<cModuleB>("cModuleB", init<std::string, bool>())
      .def("printFunc", &cModuleB::printFunc);
}
```

> submodule/submodule.hpp # The submodule containing the c++ class

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace testspace {

   class SubModuleClass {

     public:
            SubModuleClass(string name = "", bool bIsGreat = false);
            ~SubModuleClass();

            bool subModuleFunction(vector<int> & myVec);
   };
}
```

> - submodule/submodule.cpp # The c++ class definition

```
using namespace std;

#include "submodule.hpp"

using namespace testspace;

SubModuleClass::SubModuleClass(string name, bool bIsGreat)
{       
}

SubModuleClass::~SubModuleClass()
{               
}   

bool SubModuleClass::subModuleFunction(vector<int> & myVec)
{
    int nCounter = 0;
    for (vector<int>::iterator vi = myVec.begin(); vi != myVec.end(); vi++) {
        if (*vi > 1) nCounter++;
    }
    if (nCounter*2 > (int)myVec.size()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

First we compile submodule into a shared library by the following two commands:

```
g++ -MMD -MP -ffloat-store -m64 -O0 -ggdb -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG \
     -c submodule/submodule.cpp -o submodule/submodule.o

g++ -m64 -shared -Wl,-soname=cygsubmodule_for_moduleB.dll \
    -Wl,--whole-archive submodule/submodule.o -Wl,--no-whole-archive \
    -Wl,--out-implib,./libsubmodule_for_moduleB.dll.a \
    -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import \
    -o submodule/cygsubmodule.dll
```

And the we compile the actual wrapper code and link it into a boost_python dll that we should be able to import from python (verified that the included example works find on ubuntu).

```
g++ -MMD -MP -ffloat-store -m64 -O0 -ggdb -fPIC  \
    -Isubmodule -I/usr/include/python2.7 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG \
    -c moduleB/moduleB.cpp -o moduleB/moduleB.o

g++ -m64 -shared -Wl,-soname=cygmoduleB.dll \
    -Wl,--whole-archive moduleB/moduleB.o -Wl,--no-whole-archive \
    -Wl,--out-implib,./libmoduleB.dll.a -Wl,--export-all-symbols \
    -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Lsubmodule -lsubmodule -lstdc++ 
    -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -o moduleB/cygmoduleB.dll
```

In ubuntu this module can be used as is after removing the `cyg`-prefix from the `.so`file and making sure that the `submodule.so` is in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. However, cygwin shows the classic import error:

```
>>> import moduleB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No such file or directory
```

Examining the differences of `ldd` on the working moduleB between cygwin and Ubuntu one can see that the boost and python dlls have beeen replaced by question marks in the output from `moduleB.dll`.

moduleB on cygwin:

```
# ldd moduleB.dll
ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x778b0000)
kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/kernel32.dll (0x77470000)
KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7fefdfd0000)
SYSFER.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/SYSFER.DLL (0x75090000)
??? => ??? (0x4f3d00000)
```

moduleB on Ubuntu:

```
# ldd moduleB.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff55b73000)
libsubmodule.so => libsubmodule.so (0x00007fee4f9d7000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fee4f6a8000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007fee4f144000)
libboost_python-py27.so.1.55.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.55.0 (0x00007fee4eef7000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fee4ece1000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fee4e91b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fee4ddbf000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055f47c1a6000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fee4dba0000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fee4d987000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fee4d783000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fee4d580000)
```

Any idea as to why moduleB fails to identify itself as a boost_module in cygwin, and why `g++` fails to include the appropriate dependency information?

boost_python was installed using the package in cygwin.

---

**UPDATE**: 
In addition to the correct answer below, two things should be noted that obfuscated the correct solution:

1. `ldd` on cygwin does not give the same output as on `ubuntu` and  instead of `<library>.dll => not found`it only displays something like `? => ? (<address>)`
2. When loading a `boost` module in python on cygwin that depends on a `dll` not in path we do not get a message that a dll is missing, only that the boost module can not be found.

Comment: Link c++ modules with g++, period. Who said gcc or anything else should work? Anyway, show your actual build commands as invoked by make.

Comment: @n.m. I have updated the post with a complete working example.

Comment: You have a mismatch between module name and file name. You build cyfmoduleB.dll but it should be called moduleB.dll. I have reproduced your steps, renamed cygmoduleB.dll to moduleB.dll, and the result is a module that works perfectly well with Python (gcc 5.4.0, cygwin updated today).

Comment: Strange. This does not work for me, and there are still only question marks from ldd. Also, the naming requirement is true also on the linux side so for this reason there was already a copy command in place moving [lib/cyg]moduleB.[so|dll] to moduleB.[so|dll].  I also used gcc 5.4.0. Thanks a lot for trying! Any other ideas on what could differ between our two cases?

Comment: Something in your environment is messing up with your module. Open a fresh shell, create a fresh directory, unset most environment except necessary PATH, copy source and compilation commands **from this post** and try again.

Comment: Could still not achieve a working .dll from the clean slate, but apart from cleaning up the path I am unsure of what environment variables that could be messing with this, any suggestions?

Comment: I usually find that dependency walker is more reliable than `ldd` on windows. Just run it from the Cygwin shell so that you get the proper `PATH` setup. Also ensure that the `boost_python` dll you are using has been compiled for python 2.

Comment: Perhaps ???s are there because you forgot to put cygsubmodule.dll to someplace accessible (like current directory).

Comment: Embarrasingly enough it seems that @n.m. is right. I was thrown off by the differing (and more cryptic) output of `ldd` as well as the `import error` in the cygwin case. In ubuntu when not having the submodule.so in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` I get `libsubmodule.so => not found`. And in the case of trying to import such a `moduleB.so` in python with that missing the `ImportError`gives the explanation: `ImportError: libsubmodule.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Nevertheless, add these differences in output and I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: What's embarrassing is that my own recipe has stopped working for me today. I have tried to build a boost::python module but all I get from `import myModule` is `permission denied`. I can swear it wasn't like that when I wrote the above comments. Can you verify it's working for you?

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it was after verifying your above comment that I found that everything actually worked when copying `cygsubmodule.dll` to the same folder as `moduleB.dll`. And that the question marks and cryptic python `ImportError` reappeared when removing `cygsubmodule.dll`. Anyway so I think the correct answer here is that `ldd` as well as the `ImportError` may give cryptic errors under cygwin. Also I was previously not aware that cygwin only searches for dlls in `PATH` and not in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The combination of these three is what caused my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes must be made:

1. Link C++ programs and libraries with `g++`.
2. Python module name must match file name, so if a file is named `moduleB.dll` there should be a line that says `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(moduleB)` in there somewhere.
3. In order to actually load the module, it should be in the Python's `sys.path`, and all its dependencies should be in the windows `%PATH%` (or in the current directory, or wherever Windows allows to put dependent DLLs). `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't work in Cygwin the way it works in real Unix systems.